# What are the SDF Damping Units?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's the description of SDF joint --> axis --> dynamics --> damping, "The physical velocity dependent viscous damping coefficient of the joint."  Can you tell me what units this number is interpreted as having.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12803/what-are-the-sdf-damping-units?/) by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 165 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is Neutons per (meter per second), i.e.   N * s / m (force per velocity ) or N * m * s (torque per angular velocity) depending on joint type.

---

Originally posted by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) with karma: 163 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on 2018-05-10**:
Whence did this info come?

**Comment by [jwchang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5575/jwchang/) on 2018-06-13**:
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf#Joints, "the dynamics element with a viscous damping coefficient of 0.7 N*m*s/rad".